# EF Core Tooling 1.1.0-preview4-final Not Compatible with Net46

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an EF Core project which I recently upgraded to 1.1. Everything was working fine...until I tried to add a migration. Executing dotnet ef  on the command line now generates an error about not being able to find the ef module/program.

Digging into this a bit I discovered that there was a breaking change in the EF Core 1 -> 1.1 transition involving the tooling. In project.json you have to replace this dependency:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
```

with

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
```

Unfortunately...when I do that the package update fails with the error message that this version of the tooling does not support net46. Which I have to run under because of certain libraries that I'm using.

Here is the entire project.json file:

```
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "ConnellDataCore": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final", 
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Serilog": "2.3.0"
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "xmlDoc": false
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.IO.Compression": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "tools": {
  }
```

I should also point out that the database is defined in a standalone-assembly, so I've had to use the "create a dummy static Program::Main()" trick, along with the "create a temporary context factory" trick.

How do I go about getting back to where I was, being able to add migrations to my EF Core database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug as of early February, 2017. The workaround is to revert to an earlier version of the tooling (in the project.json file):

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final"
```

Note, too, that the assembly path changed to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.**Tools.DotNet** from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.**Tools**.

Finally, in my particular case I'd mistakenly included the references in the dependencies section of the project.json file. They really belong in the tools section:

```
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final"
  }
```